# What kind of morphisms should I expect to be proper?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm trying to learn more about proper pushforward, but I'm stuck at coming up with interesting examples of proper morphisms of schemes. The only examples I can think of are inclusions of projective schemes into projective space and families of projective schemes over a base. The latter does not form an interesting morphism of chow rings, but the former could be interesting. Are there any other cases I should be aware of?

Comment: Blow up's are proper.

Comment: I am curious: why do you say "The latter does not form an interesting morphism of chow rings"?

Comment: When I wrote that I was thinking of a morphism of curves to the affine plane, but this could be interesting to see how a cycle on a family is sent to the base. For example, I could consider a family of complete intersections parameterized by some projective space. Then a cycle of the correct dimension would have support in the points of the base whose scheme upstairs contains the cycle.

Comment: proper morphisms are the algebro-geometric notion of "having compact fibers" (as well as being separated).

Note that a (family of) projective scheme(s) $X$ over a base $B$ is just a projective morphism $X\rightarrow B$. There are various results that say that under "most" reasonable conditions, proper is the same as projective, though in general projective is slightly more restrictive. Perhaps you should google "proper vs projective" or something